# How to validate an input to see if it matches a record in the database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-server-2008, ajaxform

I am trying to create an input that queries the database and returns whether or not a result exists in the database. I have it partially working, but my box is glowing green whenever I only type in one letter. It would be better if it stayed red until it actually found a exact match and then turned green. Edit: I just realized there is also something wrong with my query. It is correctly querying the database now. The original issue is my main problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load").keyup(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
       ;

    searchRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'check_load_no.php',
        data: $('#load').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".verify").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 9px 2px #84f850');
            $(".error").css('display', 'none');
            $(".success").css('display', 'block');

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(".verify").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 9px 2px #ad0037');
            $(".success").css('display', 'none');
            $(".error").css('display', 'block');
        }

    });

    });
   });
```

Below is my php

```
<?php include('../model/conn.php'); ?>
<?php include('../model/conn2.php') ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT cmt_2 FROM oeordhdr_sql WHERE cmt_2 = '{$_POST['load']}'";
$query = (odbc_exec($conn,$sql));
$row = (odbc_fetch_row($query));
if($row['cmt_2']){
    echo 'yeah';
}
```

HTML

```
  <h1>Please add the info based on your load number</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="card" >
            <input class="verify" id="load" type="text" name="load" placeholder="Load Number" required/>
    <span class="error" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"> </i>I'm not finding anything</span>   
    <span class="success" style="display: none;"> <i class="fa fa-check-cube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Congratulations, that record exists!</span><br> 
<button  class="update_button" type="submit" name="add" value="update">Update</button></div></form>
```

Comment: Maybe only run the query if at least 2-3 characters have been entered?

Comment: Note: Use `odbc_prepare()` before `odbc_exec()` for security reasons - read - http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php

Comment: I was under the impression odbc_exec() prepares and executes?http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php There is also an odbc_execute that requires you to prepare first.

Comment: This is susceptible to SQL injection since your are concatenating the user input into your SQL. You should use parametrized prepared statements instead.

Comment: @MikeBrant Example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection or maybe more famously - https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @MikeBrant http://www.java2s.com/Code/Php/MySQL-Database/functionodbcexecaccomplishestherolesofbothodbcprepareandodbcexecute.htm

Comment: @EdgarsAivars Not sure why commenting me on your link.  I said nothing about the method not performing a prepared statement. It does.  It does not however perform a parametrized prepared statement.  It does not magically escape the SQL string passed to it either.  Thus, we still have SQL injection vulnerability. Using `odbc_prepare()` and `odbc_execute()` separately would allow you to pass parameters. `odbc_exec()` should only be used for cases where you do not need parameters in your query. This use case should utilize parameters in the prepared statement.

Comment: @MikeBrant Sorry if i misunderstand - if you see my first comment in this thread i say that you need to use prepared statements, but quick look at `odbc_exec()` made me believe that it is shorthand for both `odbc_prepare()` and  `odbc_execute()` functions. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to output the error/success message using php instead of changing css

```
$("#load").keyup(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();


    searchRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'check_load_no.php',
        data: $('#load').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data==="yeah")
            {
                $(".validate").html(data);

            }
            else
            {
                $(".validate").html(data);


            }
        }

    });

    });
```

My php

```
 $sql = "SELECT cmt_2 FROM oeordhdr_sql WHERE cmt_2 LIKE '{$_POST['load']}'";
    $query = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    $row = (odbc_fetch_row($query));
    if($row){
        echo '<span class="success" style="display: block;"> <i class="fa fa-check-cube fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Congratulations, that record exists!</span>';

    }else{
        echo'<span class="error" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"> </i>I\'m not finding anything</span>';
    }
```

My HTML

```
<h1>Please add the info based on your load number</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="card" >
            <input class="verify" id="load" type="text" name="load" placeholder="Load Number" required/>
    <div class="validate"></div><br> 
<button  class="update_button" type="submit" name="add" value="update">Update</button></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data) {
     if(data==="yeah")
     {
        $(".verify").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 9px 2px #84f850');
        $(".error").css('display', 'none');
        $(".success").css('display', 'block');
     }
     else
     {
        $(".verify").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 9px 2px #ad0037');
        $(".success").css('display', 'none');
        $(".error").css('display', 'block');
     }
}
```

check if response is what you need and only then add .success class

Comment: That gives me the same result. Edit: Actually that makes it not do anything. no glowing red or green

Comment: i just thought class .error you made for handler error , but now i think its for response? if there is no such data in db then you add class .error?

Comment: It is staying red now and never turning green. I checked the database and there are white spaces.3259267999                         . So I tried it with white spaces, still no luck.

Comment: i dont know if you noticed there was error in my code - forgot one curly brace dont know if it helps. i edited it

Comment: I changed the "=" in my query to LIKE, now it is returning "yeah" when the full number is input, but not turning green any other ideas?

Comment: what you get when you add `console.log(typeOf data);` as `success: function (data) { console.log(typeOf data); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116824/discussion-between-edgars-aivars-and-ryan).

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler will not be called even if "yeah" is not echoed out by PHP script, as the server response would still be HTTP 200.  For this reason, your success handler will always trigger (unless of course there is an actual problem with your server/application).

If you want to trigger the error handler, you would have to have the server send a 400 or 500 series HTTP response code (likely 404 in this case) for the case when no match is found.

Alternately, you could just put all your logic in the success handler and not change your server-side code at all.  You would just have to test for the value of "yeah" being present or not.

You should also consider adding/removing CSS classes on your DOM elements rather than specifically specifying the CSS in your function.  This would allow you to later change the CSS if needed, without having to alter this function.

Comment: I also tried putting the logic in the success handler. It is staying red now and never turning green. I checked the database and there are white spaces after the number.3259267999 . So I tried it with white spaces, still no luck.

Comment: I changed the "=" in my query to LIKE, now it is returning "yeah" when the full number is input, but not turning green any other ideas?